# How to select or see recently saved file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone know how to see/open the log of recently saved files in visual studio code?

I need to know this because I want to find out which files I have edited recently

Comment: in the terminal `ls -lt`  or `ls -lrt`

Comment: open **vscode** 
press `CTRL + P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to File > open Recent

or Ctrl + r and search for the file. its list of recent folders first and then recent file so if you looking for file just scroll down a bit